# how to add redirect to asp.net rows

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a grid like this,

```
    <asp:GridView ID="pgv" CssClass="Grid" runat="server" ShowHeader="false" AllowPaging="False" OnRowCreated="pgv_RowCreated"></asp:GridView>
```

This is how i am populating it,

```
 List<FruitObject> fruitList = new List<FruitObject>();
fruitList = GetFruitNameAndURL();
          pgv.DataSource = fruitList;
                pgv.DataBind();
```

**But now for each row of fruit I have a url, on click I want rows to navigate to the url, is there anyway I can do it in page load ?**

FruitObject has two strings,  Name and URL.

Comment: Are you asking how to navigate to another URL onclick of a row (TR)?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this on the [RowDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event.

Add to your GridView declaration the OnRowDataBound attribute and handler, like this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="pgv" CssClass="Grid" runat="server" 
  ShowHeader="false" 
  AllowPaging="False" 
  OnRowCreated="pgv_RowCreated" 
  OnRowDataBound="pgv_RowDataBound"></asp:GridView>
```

In your code behind page, add your handler

```
void pgv_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
  {

    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
      //get the underlying datasource object for the row
      FruitObject fo = (FruitObject)e.Row.DataItem;
      e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", string.Format("window.location = '{0}", fo.URL));
    }

  }
```

This is assuming your FruitObject has a property of URL.

Comment: thank you, what if I don't have row in second column, i up voted you

Comment: can i add value or something hidden to datarow

Comment: Are you saying you don't have the URL showing in the gridview?

Comment: Nope, I want to keep url hidden

Comment: fo contains the individual FruitObject the row is bound to. fo.URL would be getting the property of the FruitObject which contains the URL. If your URL is stored in a different property, then use that. For example, if your URL is accessed via a property called myurl, then just access it like fo.myurl.